# Pass ListBox Name as Parameter to use in a Function - ACCESS VBA

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, listbox

I am trying to create a function which delete all the Items listed in a ListBox. However, when I Try to pass the name of the ListBox, it returns an error: Inavlid Parameters.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function CleanList(ListName As ListBox)
Dim intItemsInList As Integer
Dim intCounter As Integer

intItemsInList = ListName.ListCount

For intCounter = 0 To intItemsInList - 1
    ListName.RemoveItem 0
Next

End Function
```

Here is how I am calling the function:

```
Call CleanList(List_List1.Name)
```

The name of the ListBox I am using is `List_List1`

If I don't type the Method `.Name`, it shows the first Item of the List. I have tried without the Parentheses, without success.

Could you help me?

Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't accept a string (listbox name), but a Listbox object.

Which is the best way for a function like that.

So when calling the function, you only pass the object, not its name:

```
Call CleanList(Me!List_List1)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! 
But if I want to use the ".Name", I have changed the function to an String. However, when the other method inside the function ".ListCount" is running I get an error for "Invalid Qualifier". How I am suppose to solve this? Thanks Again

Comment: Again, it is best to pass the object, not the name. To resolve the name, you would need to pass the form as well, but that makes no sense. `Call CleanList(Me, "List_List1")`